# Questions about good practices with MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a simple MVC application with VS and Entity Framework, i have few questions.

1. I want to add some default values to my model, i can do that by
   including default values to constructor like this:

   ```
   public Worker()
   {
       WorkerActive = true;
   }
   ```

   But default controller code is like this, and it's not returning anything

   ```
   public ActionResult Create()
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

   If i change that to this, it works but i'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong:

   ```
   public ActionResult Create()
   {
       return View(new Worker());
   }
   ```

   Are there any problems here?
2. I have a combobox with all workers in it, i want to show some
   records based on the selection. For example, i want to show all
   records where **WorkerId=ComboboxValue**. I can do this easily
   by using this:

   ```
   workers = m.Workers.Where(w => w.BranchId == curUser.BranchId).ToList<Worker>();
   ```

   But it's in a view. Is using
   statements like where in view a bad practice? I can add a new method
   to controller like **getUsersByBranch(BranchId)** and use that.
   What's the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Your first `Create()` method does not pass the model to the view

Comment: I think you need to go and read up on the basics of ASP.NET MVC.  There are lots of parts to it including many conventions that you need to know about.  When you use `View(OBJECT)` you are passing the object to your view to be rendered.  As a comment relating to your initial comment about a default value, you can add the following attribute to your Worker.WorkActive property: `[DefaultValue(true)]` and you can remove the assignment in your constructor.

Comment: In the future I would suggest breaking multiple questions into separate individual questions on Stackoverflow.  It keeps it cleaner and if someone only knows one answer it will allow them to just answer that part rather than not answering at all.

Comment: First code created by VS itself. I added return View(new Worker()); myself and i was asking if it's right thing to do or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I'd argue that your models should be as stupid as possible, just properties and metadata.  Your controller can certainly have logic in it to manipulate the model, though.  That's what it's for - to return the model to the view, however you see fit:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     var model = new Worker { WorkerActive = true };
     return View(model);
 }
```

Plus, you won't have to worry about needing different default values in a different controller.

2) The view is 'supposed' to be pretty dumb too.  But as with all best practices, it really comes down to the overhead of refactoring and the potential gain.  No, that code probably shouldn't be in your view.  Ideally, if it's required by the view, it'd be a property of some sort on your model, that you controller has set up.

The logic with the 'best practice' of simple views is that it can get overly convoluted very quickly if you keep doing this, leading to spaghetti code.  But like I said, you should try things and see if **you** like them sometimes, instead of simply going along blindly with best practices.

---

by 'property on your model' I mean:

```
public class CreateModel
{
     public List<User> UsersInBranch { get; set; }
}
```

then your controller can fill it in, like above.  Keeps your view cleaner, and lets the controller perform it's intended functionality.  With MVC and Razor, logic in your view is not *really* in your view (in my mind), because it's still running server side.  It feels like mixing server and client side operations to me.

Comment: Thanks, i'm pretty clear about first question but not about second one. So, i shouldn't use things like "where" in view, but i was thinking like add a method to  my controller named something like "getUsersByBranch(BranchId)". I won't change anything in my model, i don't understand what you mean by "preoperty of your model".

Comment: @user5273382 I added some info

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. It seems i need to read much more before coding.

Comment: @user5273382 like I said, it comes down to what *you* like.  As long as you're staying up to date on best practices (most importantly **why** they are considered best practices), and code with those in the back of your mind, you'll be fine.  No application can follow best practices to the letter, there's always something that needs tweaking

Comment: Yes, i know it won't be perfect but it's a great time to learn best practices because i'm pretty new to MVC and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Worker());
}
```

No problems in here, but Worker is a Entity? Maybe you should separate infrastructure (ef mapping) code from presentation (mvc).

```
workers = m.Workers.Where(w => w.BranchId == curUser.BranchId).ToList<Worker>();
```

Don't do this in your View. It would be better if you move this code to repository. Take a look at the good paper from Martin Fowler about this pattern:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: Thanks, Worker is a entity, yes. What do you mean by seperate it?

Comment: @user5273382 take a look at onion architecture: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808400/Onion-Architecture-in-ASP-Net-MVC